# Laravel datatable not showing

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm using yajra laravel datatable package with laravel 5.8. Datatable is not showing in my view. I added datatable after jquery. I can not figure out where is the problem. Help me to solve this. Thanks.

datatable script:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
 $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: '/get_appointment_data',
  columns: 
  [
   {
    data: 'id', 
    name: 'id'
   },
   {
    data: 'date', 
    name: 'date'
   },
   {
    data: 'time', 
    name: 'time'
   },
   {
    data: 'payment_status', 
    name: 'payment_status'
   }
  ]
 })
} );
```

Controller code:

```html
    public function getAppointmentData(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $getData = DB::table('jobs')->select('id', 'date', 'time', 'payment_status', 'amount')->get();
            $datatable = DataTables::of($json)->make(true);
            return $datatable;
        } 
    }
    public function ShowAppointments(Request $request)
    {
        return view('admin.show_appointments');
    }
```

Routes:

```html
Route::get('/show_appointments', 'NavigationController@ShowAppointments')->name('show_appointments');
Route::get('/get_appointment_data', 'NavigationController@getAppointmentData');
```

I want to show the datatable in admin.show_appointments view return in ShowAppointments method

HTML in view:

```html
        <table class="table" id="appointment-datatable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">id</th>
                <th scope="col">date</th>
                <th scope="col">time</th>
                <th scope="col">payment_status</th>
                <th scope="col">amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
       </table>
```

I never used datatables before and i'm new to laravel. Appreciate your help!

Comment: can you post the error you're getting

Comment: You can try to use your jquery script in header. I think your jquery script is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Make Changes like this:
Hopefully it'll help you

**Route File :**

```
Route::get('/appointments','NavigationController@Appointments')->name('appointments');
```

**Html Code:**

Put this in your head section

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And this is your table:

```
<table class="table" id="appointment-datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">id</th>
        <th scope="col">date</th>
        <th scope="col">time</th>
        <th scope="col">payment_status</th>
        <th scope="col">amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public function Appointments(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data =  DB::table('jobs')->select('id', 'date', 'time', 'payment_status', 'amount')->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->make(true);
        }

        return view('admin.show_appointments');
    }
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
$(function () {

    $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('appointments') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
            {data: 'time', name: 'time'},
            {data: 'payment_status', name: 'payment_status'},
        ]
    });

  });
```

I hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding token in your header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

And in your ajaxSetup or data add the token

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Also change getAppointmentData function.

```
public function getAppointmentData(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            $getData = DB::table('jobs')->select('id', 'date', 'time', 
            'payment_status', 'amount');
            return DataTables::of($getData)->make(true);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I made the changes according to yours. But still datatable is not showing. `Route::get('/get_appointment_data', 'NavigationController@getAppointmentData');` shows the accurate json return. where is the problem?

Comment: Problem solved. Does anyone know how to format datatable pdf which exporte from pdf button in datatable?